# when trying to sudo apt install git, i get the following error

Tags: 22.04, git

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

You can install liberror-perl manually from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-main-arm64/liberror-perl_0.17029-1_all.deb.html and then install Git normally.

It works for me